# How to add an editable text box to a page

Tags: 7, forms

So i have created a page which uses an XML feed to generate some output. I want to be able to add a textarea from the FORM API so that i can allow user of my site to enter some details on to the form itself.

Similar functionality to how entityform works, seemed like a simple task, but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_notes

Comment: OK thanks for your answer, for something that should be an easy functionality was kind of an issue. Managed to find some information on how to do it using a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thought i would answer my own question and show the method in which this is done. First declare a block, with a block view and then define a custom callback function that defines the textarea, are any output from Drupal's Form API.

```
function hook_block_info() {
  $blocks['box_question'] = array(
    'info' => t('Box question area'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block['subject'] = t('TEST');
  $block['content'] .= drupal_render(drupal_get_form('custom_block_form'));
  return $block;
}

function custom_block_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['question'] = array(
    '#markup' => 'this is a block,
  );
  $form['answer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#resizable' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => $default,
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#name' => 'save',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('save-button'),
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

The custom_block_form is what defines the form blocks, call the submit functions to make your own callback on what to do when the form is saved.